# Swift: Setting the text of a label in a URLSessionTask

Tags: swift, uilabel, urlsession

So I am downloading a JSON file using a URLRequest().
I parse through it in order to get a specific string and I want to set the text of a label I have in my ViewController to that specific string.
I use a CompletionHandler in order to retrieve the function that gets the JSON file from another Swift file.

Here is the code of calling the function and setting the label:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    tr = TransportServices()
    tr.getLyftData(origin: originstring, destination: destinationstring){ json in
     //Parsing JSON in order to get specific data
        self.lyftlabel.text = stringexample
    }
}
```

and here is the code of getting the JSON

```
func getLyftData(origin: String, destination: String, completionHandler: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> ()){


    let urlrequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlstring)!)


    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let sessions = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = sessions.dataTask(with: urlrequest) {(data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("error, did not receive data")
            return
        }
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: Any]{
                completionHandler(json)
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error with URL Request")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This does the job, but in a very slow manner. I know that there is a runtime issue because UILabel.text must be set from main thread only, but I don't know any other way to fix it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set label text in main thread use this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

self.lyftlabel.text = stringexample

}
```

Comment: Thanks, where would I call this function?

Comment: Just replace it with `self.lyftlabel.text = stringexample` line